# if referrer domain = x, redirect to page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to detect the referrer domain to my Rails site, and if the referrer matches a domain I would like them to be redirected to a specific page.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the restrition at ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :check_referer

  private

  def check_referer
    if request.referer =~/.hotdeals\.com./
      flash[:info] = "You are being redirected to a proper place"
      redirect_to url
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def my_action
    if request.referer =~ /a_domain_pattern/
      redirect_to a_specific_page_path
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @chendriksen, like [any other](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html).